# Homotopy type of specific space of matrices

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I would like to determine topological properties of $\mathbb R^8$ minus the set determined by the equation
$$
\mathrm{det}\begin{pmatrix}
a-a' & b-b'\\
c-c' & d-d'
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
where $a,a',b,b',c,c',d,d'\in\mathbb R$.

How do I determine the homotopy type and how many connected components this space has? If this does not turn out to be a standard space, I would also like to determine (co)homology groups.

Comment: $A$ such that $\mathrm{det}A\dots$?

Comment: Although there are $8$ parameters, the space of matrices has only 4 degrees of freedom, and the way you've described it, it is homeomorphic to $GL(2,R)$. Perhaps you want to ask what is the subset of $\mathbb R^8$ described by the condition that the above determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Assuming that's what you want, your space has a continuous map to GL(2,R), which you could try showing is a homotopy equivalence. (Just speculating, I haven't thought about it carefully.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote your subset of $\mathbb R^8$ by $X$. Then there is a surjective continuous map $X\to GL(2,\mathbb R)$. The homotopy type of $GL(2,R)$ is two copies of $SL(2,R)$. Anyway, from this you can already tell that $X$ has at least two connected components! Now, I claim that $X$ is actually homotopy equivalent to $GL(2,R)$. Given an $8$-tuple in $X$, perform a homotopy where $(a,a')\mapsto (a-t,a'-t)$ for $t\in[0,a]$. Similarly do this for the other coordinates. This deformation retracts $X$ onto the space where $a=b=c=d=0$. Which is exactly $GL(2,R)$. As mentioned by user8268, $SL(2,R)\simeq S^1$, so $X\simeq S^1\cup S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Change the coordinates: replace $a',\dots d'$ with $A=a-a',\dots,D=d-d'$. Then you see that the space is $GL_2(\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}^4$, which is homotopy equivalent to $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, and hence to $O_2(\mathbb{R})$, which is a disjoint union of two circles.

Comment: He said the complement of the set $\det=0$.

Comment: @JimConant: oh I see; I edited out that discussion.